# AS3 URLVariables Unescaping Data

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a PHP file that is queried for information, and it passes a couple of variables back. One variable contains a JSON string with a variable in the object called message, which comes escaped to prevent it from causing issues if the message has an ampersand, single quote, etc in it.

```
&data={"message":"star%27s"}
```

Obviously the data sent is more complicated, this is just an example. After I take the data passed back by the PHP file and use URLVariables to decode it and access the "data" variable, it ends up looking like:

```
{"message":"star's"}
```

At this point I can't parse the JSON string, it will throw an error because of the single quote. Encoding it wouldn't work, it would encode more than just everything after the colon.

Is there a way to keep it from converting it? I was thinking I could manually parse the PHP returned string, but it seems unnecessary and I don't want risk running into issues later on because of it. I looked at the AS3 API and I couldn't find anything documenting this or how to disable it.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Is that really invalid JSON? I don't think the single quote should cause any problems.

Comment: Agreed, why does the single quote cause a problem in parsing a string delineated by double quotes? (mostly curious but explaining that might help some of us understand the issue better). Also, what are you using for JSON parsing, the built in JSON class in Flash Player 11 or the older parser in that AS3 Core lib swc?

Comment: I'm using the native JSON parser included in Flash 11. I don't know, but my entire JSON string failed to decompile due to someone using a single quote in a word. I've searched around and read that a forward slash or backslash can break it too (forgot which one). Either way I ended up just splitting up the variables and data and unescaping the message manually and it worked great.

Comment: Just checked, it managed to decode the first line of code in my original post above just fine even after it turned into a single quote, must have been something else.

Answer (score 0):

You try with

Actionscript API escape() and unescape() see for more details [Escape and unescape](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000614.html#162679)

Also look at JSON.parse and JSON.stringify [working-with-native-json-in-flash-player-11](http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/07/working-with-native-json-in-flash-player-11/)

JSON decode in actionscript see [decode-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667291/how-to-decode-json-using-native-json-or-actionjson-in-flex-3)