# how grails communicate with Flex using JSON

Tags: json, apache-flex, grails, flash-builder

i have to create a application on grails with UI in Flex.i have to use JSON which will help in communication between java and flex.for grails code i am using IntellijIdea and for flex development i am using AdobeFlash Builder. I have no idea how both will communicate.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: Have you tried the flex plugin? http://grails.org/plugin/flex May be a start point to you.

Comment: i want to use flash builder for flex development so i used blazeds for connectivity part but blazeds is not allowing me to expose groovy files it is asking for java service files.And also i read somewhere that this is compatible till grails 1.3

Comment: I guess I don't really understand the question.  JSON is not a method of communication; but a data format, like XML or AMF.  You can send JSON from Flex to a server side language using the HTTPService class.  You can process JSON inside the Flash Player using the JSON class.

Comment: i will use HTTPService for sending JSON from flex to server side language.

Answer (score 1):

See this links

[How to decode Json using native JSON or actionjson in Flex 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667291/how-to-decode-json-using-native-json-or-actionjson-in-flex-3)

http://andrewalbrecht.com/content.php?pageID=111

regars